# Sending message from form with PHP. Place multiple variables on one line

Tags: variables, line

I created a form in html and the data is consumed and sent via PHP. The email sends fine but the format is wrong inside the email. For example the date has three variables "pick_up_date", pick_up_date_2" and pick_up_date_3".

These are month, day and year. I want it to display 02 21 2014 but it displays 02212014. Below is the code I used in PHP but did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $email_message .= "Pick Up Date: ".clean_string($pick_up_date). "". ($pick_up_date_2). "". ($pick_up_date_3)."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put spaces in between the "".

```
$email_message .= "Pick Up Date: ".clean_string($pick_up_date). " ". ($pick_up_date_2). " ". ($pick_up_date_3)."\n";
```